# Nivo Line Formatting time tick on the x axis

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, graph, axis-labels

I want to format the x-axis of the line chart with time I am using [@nivo/line](https://nivo.rocks/line/) react library for charts

```
 axisBottom={{
   tickValues: 3,
   tickRotation: 90,
   format: (values) => `${getRequiredDateFormat(values, 'MMMM-DD')}`, // using momentjs to format   
   legendOffset: -80,
   legendPosition: 'start',
}}
```

[image: Chart output]

Just want to display each month to appear once based on data.

[CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-kowalevski-r89yp?file=/src/App.js)  Try Here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a new array of all x-axis dates and then show the date once if it appears multiple times.

Here is a working example -

https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-leftpad-dwmb9?file=/src/App.js&fbclid=IwAR1dZoKls-dVowdVRoN3pZd8INsHgc2egNdcNLkj3n0nDqMpJQIJdK6vyQ8